# Can I grep for multiple patterns but have some be inverse?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep

I know that I can search for multiple patterns like so

```
    grep -e 'pattern1|pattern2' file
```

and I can invert the grep search like so

```
    grep -v 'pattern' file
```

but is there a way I can grep for one pattern while simultaneously doing an inverse grep for another?

```
    grep -e 'pattern I want' -v 'pattern I do not want' file
```

Comment: With PCRE patterns, yes. That is, you need a GNU grep, or pcregrep.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - what would that look like? I'm not doubting your words, just genuinely curious as I haven't seen such use with grep yet ...

Comment: `grep -Pe '^(?!.*pattern I do not want).*pattern I want'`

Comment: Isn't that order specific, Wiktor?

Comment: The classic idiom is `grep a | grep -v b`, but we can do better than two procs, right? :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may use `awk` as an alternative:

```
awk '/pattern I want/ && !/pattern I do not want/' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming suitably quoted patterns,

```
 sed -n "/$pat1/ { /$pat2/ d; p; }" file
```

`-n` tells `sed` not to print unless explicitly requested.
`/$pat1/ { ... }` says on lines matching $pat1, execute the commands in the braces.
`/$pat2/ d;` says on lines with $pat2, `d`elete, which automatically cycles to the next line of input and ignores any more commands for this line, skipping the `p`. If it does not see $pat2, the `d` doesn't fire and proceeds to...
`p` means print the current line.

My example:

```
$: grep '#if ' dcos-deploy.sh
#if   (( ${isPreProd:-0} ))
#if [[ "$target_mesosphere_cluster" != CDP ]]

$: pat1="^#if "
$: pat2="\\[\\["

$: sed -En "/$pat1/ { /$pat2/ d; p; }" dcos-deploy.sh
#if   (( ${isPreProd:-0} ))
```